# Session being overridden in spring security application

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, security, session

In a spring security application i am navigating to the login page and entering my credentials and getting logged in.Now again if i open a new tab in the same browser and navigate to the login url it shows me the login page.If I enter another users credentials and login my previous Jsession ID(ie: the one created in the previous tab) is getting overridden with the new jsession id.Upon refreshing the previous tab the session is overridden.

I want to implement that if a user is logged in already in the application, upon navigating to the url again in another tab on the same browser the homepage of the application should open. 
Please advise as how I can accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

Since the server uses the cookie to map to the current session, you'd have to control how the browser sends cookies. Every time a request is sent to a website from a new tab, most browsers will send all the cookies it has for that domain. Since your ***server received the same session cookie***, it will treat this request as being in the same session. There's no way it can tell the difference.

Therefore, as far as cookie-based web sessions go at least, you probably won't be able to force the creation of a new session upon opening a new tab.